# CompletableFuture and a loop in Java

Tags: java

I have the following code

```
            Iterator<StepNode> iterator = stepNodeHolder.getStepNodeList().iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                StepNode stepNode = iterator.next();
                ps.setString(1, stepNode.getUniqueItemId());
                ps.setString(2, stepNode.getUniqueStepId());
                if (iterator.hasNext())
                    ps.addBatch();
        }
```

Since I already have the `iterator`, can I run this loop in parallel to perform `addBatch` using `CompletableFuture`. I have about 3000 items in the iterator and is there any way to run `addBatch()` in parallel for all these 3000 items?

Edit :

`ps` is `PreparedStatement`. I'm just adding the `Bean` values to the `addBatch` which is a `JDBC` method

Comment: What are you doing here? What is `ps`?

Comment: @John Kugelman addBatch is for JDBC input.

Comment: @JohnKugelman : Updated my question

Comment: The interface to `PreparedStatement`, especially around setting parameters and adding batches doesn't look thread safe at all to me, so I don't think this approach will work.

Comment: `if (iterator.hasNext())` inside `while (iterator.hasNext())` looks so weird. Totally don't understand what you are doing.

Comment: @waltersu: I agree that I have not given you full context. However I'm just checking that `if (iterator.hasNext())` because `SpringBatch` does it's own `addBatch` if `if (iterator.hasNext()) == null` . I don't want that too happen. So I made that statement

Comment: I agree with @msandiford. Batching your queries is generally enough and if you truly want concurrent access, you should create a connection per thread